# how to solve this machine puzzle ? using brute force algorithm and C++

Tags: c++

this question is included in my final term project (deadline after a couple of days) and Iam still trying to figure out how to solve it using C++ and brute force algorithm this is the link of the problem:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/cody/problems/44719-penny-distribution-machine
can some one help me ? this the code that i have tried :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{ 
    int n;
    int x;
    cout << "enter the amount of coins" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter size of array:" << "\n";
    cin >> x;
    int* a = new int(x);
    a [0] = n;
    for (int i = 1; i < x; i++) {
    a[i] = 0;
```

i know it is incomplete but i dont now
how to complete

Comment: `int* a = new int(x);` Did you mean `new int[x]`? Also, why not use `std::vector` (or even `std::array` since the size of your container seems unchanging)?

Comment: Notice that in the example `N=9` the final configuration is `1 0 0 1`. That happens to be the base-2 representation of `9`. Is that just a coincidence? (Maybe it's the number in reverse?)

Comment: @Matt yeah i think it's the binary digits in reverse order. because look at 4. 4 => 2 1 => 0 2 => 0 0 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Matt is right that the final configuration will always be the binary representation of the starting number with low bit to high bit ordered as the boxes, from zeroth to nth box, and the number of iterations for *n* boxes seems to be around 2*n* but i'm not sure of the exact details.

Anyway to actually do the simulation, in C++ you can use a vector of ints for the boxes and just let the size of the vector track the number of boxes you need since vectors are resizeable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

void distribute_pennies(std::vector<int>& boxes, std::vector<int>::iterator iter) {
    *(iter++) -= 2;
    if (iter == boxes.end()) {
        boxes.resize(boxes.size() + 1);
        iter = boxes.end() - 1;
    }
    ++(*iter);
}

std::tuple<int, int> num_boxes_and_iterations_for_n_pennies(int n) {
    static const auto two_or_more = [](int v) { return v >= 2; };
    std::vector<int> boxes = { n };
    int iteration_count = 0;
    std::vector<int>::iterator next_box_iter;
    while ((next_box_iter = 
            std::find_if(boxes.begin(), boxes.end(), two_or_more)) != boxes.end()) {
        distribute_pennies(boxes, next_box_iter);
        ++iteration_count;
    }
    return { static_cast<int>(boxes.size()), iteration_count };
}

int main() {
    auto [num_boxes, iterations] = num_boxes_and_iterations_for_n_pennies(9);
    std::cout << "boxes => " << num_boxes << "\n";
    std::cout << "iterations => " << iterations << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for help @jwezorek, but when i inserted the code into the VS 2022 there was some problems with the int main function it was telling me that identifier num_boxes is undefined , it also cannot deduce 'auto' type

Comment: Thanks  very much for help, but when i inserted the code into the VS 2022 there was some problems with the int main function  it was telling me that identifier num_boxes is undefined , it also cannot deduce 'auto' type @jwezorek

Comment: change the language dialect to C++17

Comment: The number of iterations is `max(0, (N & ~1) - 1)` I believe.

Comment: the function called as :num_boxes_and_iterations_for_n_pennies , I cannot understand what exactly it does @jwezorek

Comment: it puts the number of pennies it gets in a one element vector, then it iteratively finds the first item in the vector with two or more pennies in it and does the distribution step, resizing the vector if necessary, until there is no such item in the vector. Then it returns the size of the vector -- which is the number of "boxes" -- and the number of iterations as a tuple of ints.